# How to remove space before bullet in wordpress post?

Tags: css, wordpress

[image]

How we can remove space before bullet in wordpress post. The bullet remains the same but the space before the bullet. It should be removed somehow.

Comment: Can you share your post/page link ?

Comment: Make sure `ul` element CSS of your post `margin: 0` and `padding: 0`;

Comment: this link bullet, https://www.exam2jobs.prachidigital.in/supreme-court-personal-assistant-online-form-2019/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the value

```
ul, ol {
    margin: 0 0 1.5em 1.3em !important;
}
```

Comment: Glad to help :)